# Bootstrap navbar-right not aligning nav-items to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a website navbar with a navbar toggler for mobile, and I am trying to get two nav-items (for login/registration, etc.) to align to the right of the navbar but for whatever reason, the suggested method of using the `navbar-right` class won't work.

Here's the code:

```
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.php"><img src="/assets/img/logo_white.png" style="height: 35px;"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li class="nav-item <?php if ($sect == 'home') { echo 'active';} ?>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/index.php">Home</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown <?php if ($sect == 'about') { echo 'active';} ?>">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        About
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item <?php if ($page == 'about-us') { echo 'active';} ?>" href="/about/about-us.php">About Us</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item <?php if ($page == 'staff') { echo 'active';} ?>" href="/about/staff.php">Staff Team</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item <?php if ($page == 'partners') { echo 'active';} ?>" href="/about/partners.php">Partners</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown <?php if ($sect == 'resources') { echo 'active';} ?>">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Resources
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item <?php if ($page == 'downloads') { echo 'active';} ?>" href="/resources/downloads.php">Downloads</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item <?php if ($page == 'charts') { echo 'active';} ?>" href="/resources/charts.php">Charts</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item <?php if ($page == 'metar') { echo 'active';} ?>" href="/resources/metar.php">METAR Decoder</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item <?php if ($sect == 'academy') { echo 'active';} ?>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/academy/index.php">Academy</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item <?php if ($sect == 'fly') { echo 'active';} ?>">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Fly</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item <?php if ($sect == 'forums') { echo 'active';} ?>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="https://forums.multicrew.co.uk/">Forums</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item <?php if ($sect == 'book') { echo 'active';} ?>">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="https://multicrew.setmore.com/">Book</a>
                </li>
                
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="https://portal.multicrew.co.uk/"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="https://portal.multicrew.co.uk/register"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Register</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--/END Navbar-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at your site link you are using bootstrap 4,  which does not use the class 'navbar-right' like bootstrap 3

i found some examples of bootstrap 4 navigation that may help you with the layout of your menu,
https://www.codeply.com/go/qhaBrcWp3v
hope it helps

Comment: Huh, I never knew it wasn't supported now. That's weird considering it's pretty useful. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent examples

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the `navbar-right` class in your code with the **Bootstrap 4 class** `ml-auto` (margin-left:auto) and now it's working as desired.

Here's the working code snippet (click the "run code snippet" button below):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark navbar-static-top bg-dark">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.php"><img src="https://picsum.photos/55" style="height: 35px;"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/index.php">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    About
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item active" href="/about/about-us.php">About Us</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item " href="/about/staff.php">Staff Team</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item " href="/about/partners.php">Partners</a>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Resources
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item " href="/resources/downloads.php">Downloads</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item " href="/resources/charts.php">Charts</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item " href="/resources/metar.php">METAR Decoder</a>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="/academy/index.html">Academy</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Fly</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://forums.multicrew.co.uk/">Forums</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://multicrew.setmore.com/">Book</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://portal.multicrew.co.uk/"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://portal.multicrew.co.uk/register"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Register</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```